# Animation ends with error in custom interactive transitioning animation?

Tags: ios, core-animation, uiviewanimationtransition

I am setting up a custom transitioning animation. Everything works fine except the error at the end of the animation:

[image]

As you see, after the interactive animation, the animation just excutes again.

This is the method i use to handle the the interactive gesture in the class the conforms to `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` and `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`:

```
func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let maxMov:CGFloat = -300
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(recognizer.view!.superview!)
    if(translation.y < 0){
        let value = (translation.y < maxMov) ? maxMov : translation.y
        let progress = value / maxMov
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .Changed:
            updateInteractiveTransition(progress)

        case .Cancelled, .Ended:                
            if progress < 0.5 {
                self.cancelInteractiveTransition()

            } else {
                self.finishInteractiveTransition()
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom transitioning animation is based on CAAnimation whose timing is controlled by `CAMediaTiming`. In the handlePan method, you should reset the currentTiming of the container view in the transitioning.

Firstly, define a stored context which will be later assigned in the `animateTransition`method.

```
var storedContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?
```

then get it in :

```
    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    storedContext = transitionContext
    ....}
```

Then in your handlePan:

```
        case .Cancelled, .Ended:
            let transitionLayer = storedContext!.containerView().layer
            transitionLayer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        ....
```

This ensures the containerLayer's begin time equals to the time you cancel or end the gesture! Without this process, the duplicated animation would occurs.